# Commit multiple inserts with MySQLdb on Python

Tags: python, mysql, performance, mysql-python

I did a profiling of my python program and noticed that they were a lot of calls to commit and they took a lot of time.

Is it better performance wise to do :

```
db = MySQLcb.connect(...)
c = db.cursor(...)
c.execute('INSERT...)
c.commit()
c.execute('INSERT...)
c.commit()
```

or

```
db = MySQLcb.connect(...)
c = db.cursor(...)
c.execute('INSERT...)
c.execute('INSERT...)
c.commit()
```

Knowing that I am making a lot of inserts (thousands).

Comment: In [MySQLdb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html), you can use *autocommit=True* in `connect()`. And for many inserts into same table, look into `executemany`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using InnoDB tables you might find the advice on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) useful.

Most databases have facilities for bulk insert, and MySQL is no exception.

If you find your insertions slow, make sure that you don't have `autocommit` set, as this forces a transaction around each individual operation.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is really helpful !
But by question remains, do I need to do a `db.commit` after every `c.executemany(...)` I am doing ?
Or is one at the end enough ?

Comment: @flyingdutchman ... your code above does not use `executemany()` which you only have to call **once** on a list of values.

Comment: @Parfait Yes I know, but it is not the point here, I am trying to ask if I need to do a manual `commit` after each `execute` or `executemany()`

Comment: @flyingdutchman ... See my comment above where you can set *autocommit*.

Comment: I *do* know that you *can* commit after each `execute/executemany` but you don't have to. You could, however, experience performance issues if you do this in an unthinking way.